# Google Maps Very Slow in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: lubuntu, google-chrome, google-maps

For a month or more Google maps has been very slow and unusable in Chrome.  This is true even when maps load when seeking directions when searching in Chrome.  Maps is OK in Firefox.  When a web page offers links to video,like to youtube,sometimes the video box is just red with no picture.  Any suggestions?

Lubuntu  22.04.3 LTS

Chrome  Version 119.0.6045.159 (Official Build) (64-bit)

*-cpu
description: CPU
product: Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU      E5200  @ 2.50GHz
vendor: Intel Corp.
physical id: 4
bus info: cpu@0
version: 6.23.6
slot: CPU 1
size: 1403MHz
capacity: 2500MHz
width: 64 bits
clock: 800MHz

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try switching off the hardware acceleration from system tab on chrome://settings/system

Comment: that did the trick

Comment: good to hear that